# Was Edward Furlong allowed to watch "Terminator 2: Judgement Day" when it was released?

Tags: content-rating, terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

[Edward Furlong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Furlong) was 14 years old when [*Terminator 2: Judgement Day*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day) was released in 1991. And it is R-Rated.

Was Edward allowed to watch this movie with a bunch of his under-age friends? Or do they make an exception for the actor?

Actually this applies to all other R-Rated movies with child stars in them.

Comment: Related question: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/604/to-what-extent-are-child-actors-exposed-to-the-violent-aspects-of-the-movie-they

Comment: I felt my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything additional you'd like to see?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, the [Motion Picture Association of America's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system) (MPAA) film-rating system is voluntary and not enforced by law.  Still, most theaters in the United States enforce the ratings and don't let children under 17 into R-rated films without a parent or legal guardian.  So it's really up to a child actor's parents whether or not they're allowed to see an R-rated movie that they appear in.

One notable rumor ([confirmed in an interview](http://www.grouchoreviews.com/interviews/229)) where a child actor was not allowed to see an R-rated movie in which they appeared was [Olivia Hussey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivia_Hussey) who appeared in the 1968 production of [Romeo and Juliet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_and_Juliet_%281968_film%29) at the age of 16.  The film got an R-rating for nudity.  It's ironic that Hussey would not have been allowed to see the film in U.S. theaters because she was the one who appeared nude.

Comment: Source: filmratings.com (pdf) On 11/1/68, the movie rating system (MPAA) was born. With assurances that the system was voluntary — and not regulated by the government — MPAA member company studios agreed to submit all theatrical product for rating. Members of NATO agree to enforce the system by asking for identification and refusing admission to R-rated movies by unaccompanied children or to NC-17 movies by children whether or not accompanied. Retailers and rental stores also enforce the ratings for movies released on video. Assume all the adults of the film served as pseudo-parents, to allow.

Comment: My last comment consumed all my allowable characters. The last sentence (my opinion) should include the phrase "to allow Edward to attend the viewing at the premier". Thanks.

Comment: The info about Olivia Hussey.. interesting. So if it were just the child actor and his/her friends, in all probability, the theatres could deny permission. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @EknathIyer Yes, they could and probably would.  While they might be willing to look the other way for the kid who was actually *in* the movie, the friends still wouldn't have a parent or guardian present.

Comment: In regards to 'most theaters', any way to validate that? It could very well be true, but IIRC growing up, I was never denied access to an R-rated film as kid without my parents. Times change, of course.

Comment: @DA Here's a recent WSJ Law Blog article that says that most theaters enforce ratings (the article is about a notable exception). [Do Theaters Have to Enforce Movie Ratings?](http://blogs.wsj.com/law/2013/10/25/do-theaters-have-to-enforce-movie-ratings/) I grew up in the 80s and early 90s, so things might have changed concerning R-rated movies since I was young.

Comment: @BilltheLizard interesting! I guess this is one thing kids have tougher today than we did. :)

Comment: I doubt the ratings system means anything to a private screening, and the R rating merely disallows *unaccompanied* minors from being admitted. If one or both parents were there, it'd be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, he watched the movie when it was released. You can see him at the [Los Angeles premiere](http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/news-photo/actors-soleil-moon-frye-and-edward-furlong-attend-the-news-photo/156131025) here.

[image]