# Minor child actors swearing on TV

Tags: dialogue

I notice children swear a lot in TV shows, e.g. on Stranger Things. (Examples for swears: SOB, screw you, showing the middle finger, etc.), I can't remember if they've said f**k yet. In a culture where kids their age are not allowed to say these things and are constantly reprimanded to "mind their language", how is it ethical for a TV show to have them say these things? It makes me cringe at least. I know kids that age probably know these words, but is it alright to make them say it?

Do parents or some sort of children's welfare organisation not object to this? Is there an age beyond which its OK to have kids swear for acting? Because I clearly remember an episode on Modern Family where Lilly (the actor was not more than 4 years old at the time) had to say f**k a few times. It was beeped, and the producers later clarified that they had her say "fudge" while shooting the scenes. So apparently 4 is too young. How high does that bar go? What factors decide it?

Comment: Related and not sure about duplicate: [To what extent are child actors exposed to the violent aspects of the movie they perform in?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/604/27264)

Comment: I do not think it's a duplicate, as that question and its answers revolve around shielding child actors from inappropriate content. My question is about *exposing* them to what I deem is inappropriate, and whether or not the industry (and other standards) do too. And as opposed to the linked question, I know for a fact that there was no "clever dubbing or editing" used here.

Comment: That's why I said *not sure*

Comment: ["its rare to meet parents or legal guardians who’s children are in show business, while also having puritan, or otherwise conservative values. I’m not saying it never happens, I’m just saying it is rare. Point being these kids are unusually mature for their age, and they’ve already been exposed to very adult themes."](https://www.quora.com/Are-children-allowed-to-swear-on-camera-for-TV-or-film-Can-they-be-filmed-in-scenes-they-wouldnt-be-permitted-to-watch)

Comment: I don't have much of an opinion on the "ethical" aspect because I think that swearing is harmless and at times quite valuable.  I do wonder, however, how common it actually is.  While I'm from a much older generation, I certainly knew a number of curse-words at a young age, and sometimes used them when showing off to other kids (look how grown-up I am at 5 years old) but they definitely weren't a normal part of my vernacular.  If things have changed that much by now, I think that's sad -- overuse waters down the value of the words and inclines the kids towards crudity and away from eloquence.

Comment: I remember when the first *Kick-Ass* film came out, there was a bit of controversy here in the UK about the 13-year-old Hit Girl saying the C-word, but that's the only example I can remember.

Comment: This question would be improved by removing the puritanical idea that kids don't cuss or that some group should be protecting them from the evil bad words.

Answer (score 9):

[LA Weekly points out](http://www.laweekly.com/arts/from-et-to-stranger-things-an-oral-history-of-kids-cursing-on-screen-7307619) that kids cursing on screen was a 1980s development:

> Still, the baby boomers directing and penning the coming-of-age films
>   of the '80s had a tendency to subvert the wholesome representations of
>   a suburban upbringing that were prevalent throughout their own youths.
>   Rather than Beaver Cleaver and Opie Taylor uttering "Gee, golly" and
>   "Aw, shucks," kids spoke the way kids actually spoke. They were the
>   audience, after all — **what would be the point in shielding them from
>   the language they actually used?**
>
> [...]
>
> “Somewhere along the line, executives, moviemakers, storytellers,
>   realized that there was this audience there of kids who were not being
>   spoken to, who were not being presented with the things that
>   entertained them,” adds *Adventures in Babysitting* screenwriter David
>   Simkins. **“If you’re going to write for kids, to kids, about kids, I
>   think you have to, obviously, write the way they speak or risk not
>   being truthful.”**

This coincided with a change in how movies were rated:

> “Ever since the MPAA [Motion Picture Association of America] rating
>   system kicked in, the barriers to language and violence had been
>   weakening,” Dante says. “The novelty of children swearing onscreen was
>   quickly wearing off, so it became commonplace to write kids’ dialogue
>   the way it occurred in real life."
>
> **In the ‘80s, every variation of “shit” became customary for movie kids
>   to say**, whether it was “oh shit,” “holy shit,” “no shit,” “shithead,”
>   “chicken-shit,” “shit-heap,” “piece of shit,” “dog shit,” “eat shit”
>   or “you gotta be shittin’ me.”

A child actor of that era points out that cursing is part of how kids behave:

> Jeff Cohen, who played *The Goonies*’ lovable loudmouth Chunk, says most
>   of the cursing in the beloved 1985 film was the result of
>   improvisation at the behest of director Richard Donner. “He really
>   wanted us to just kind of behave like kids,” says Cohen, who's now an
>   entertainment lawyer with his own Beverly Hills firm, Cohen Gardner
>   LLP. “I hate to be the old man saying, ‘Back in the day ...,’ but I
>   think kids were less supervised in the ‘80s versus 2016. **If there’s a
>   question of ‘if kids are unsupervised how are they going to behave?’
>   the answer to that [is],” Cohen says, breaking into laughter, “they’re
>   going to fight, they’re going to curse and they’re going to be kids.**”

This even extended to the sweariest word of them all:

> “We thought it was incredibly important to keep Stephen King’s
>   original dialogue intact,” says *Stand by Me* co-screenwriter and
>   co-producer Bruce Evans. With Reiner shooting *The Princess Bride* in
>   England, Evans says it fell to him and his writing partner/co-producer
>   Raynold Gideon to fight the fight with Columbia over keeping the
>   “fucks” in the film.
>
> “There were seven of them in the movie,” Gideon adds. “Columbia wanted
>   a PG-13 film.”
>
> With the exception of *Stand by Me*, “fuck” was generally reserved for
>   ‘80s teen fodder, films like *The Breakfast Club*, *Fast Times at
>   Ridgemont High* and *Heathers*, all of which were rated R. That being
>   said, **13-year-old Billy Kopeke (Jared Rushton) delivered one of the
>   all-time great F-bombs when he demanded to know from Tom Hanks’ Josh
>   Baskin, “Who the fuck do you think you are?” in PG-rated *Big*.** In
>   *Lucas*,  Corey Haim, who played the film’s scrawny but highly
>   intelligent 14-year-old title character, brazenly stood up to the high
>   school football coach, calling him a “dumb fucking jock.”

These are just some excerpts from a very in-depth article on the topic; I recommend you go [read the whole thing](http://www.laweekly.com/arts/from-et-to-stranger-things-an-oral-history-of-kids-cursing-on-screen-7307619).

Answer (score 1):

Welfare organization? I think, with actual problems of physical and sexual abuse, violence, crime, kids not getting enough food or clothing, there isn't a welfare organization anywhere that would consider using a swearword some kind of child neglect.

I'd further question if a child using swearwords (vs an adult in the same situation) actually breaks any laws, which would be a standard for some kind of formal intervention, I'd think.

I know of a number of parents, friends and family, who use swearwords around their kids and aren't necessarily put out by if their kids use them.

Back 40+ years ago, when I hit third grade, I learned what the swear words were from hearing older kids, and every recess was, essentially, a litany of curse words streaming from my mouth, in a manner that it was clear that I had no idea what the word actually meant. I eventually toned it down, mostly because I knew how stupid I sounded. Later, I didn't swear around my kids, at all, and they didn't swear around me, but I know for a fact that, well before high school, they'd talk like that with their friends and vice versa. Now that they are both adult age, no one censors themselves when we talk, but the swearing is only occasional, because we have other things to say when we talk.

There are parent organizations that do object to swearing, of any kind, but on the level of the individual child being asked to say the lines? If you think the acting part is what introduced those words to a child, or that they never used them, before or after, outside of that part, I'd have to say that you might be a bit naive about what kids know and when they know it.

As for whether it is "acceptable" or not for TV or movies, you won't find any G-rated movies with swearing, and a lot of swearing will get you up to PG-13 or R ratings, or bleeped from non-premium cable, usually.

Comment: Although, when clicking on some different actors on "Rotten Tomatoes," I did see where they incorrectly had the movie "Brown Bunny," with its actual, real, explicit sex scene listed as "G" rated instead of "NR."  Really hope no one rents it for family movie night based on that.