# If a child is in an 18+ movie, can they still watch it?

Tags: content-rating, child-actors

I was wondering if a child actor / actress is <18 and is in an 18+ (horror?) film, would they be allowed to watch this film at a premiere, or would they have to watch it with certain scenes omitted?

Comment: I remember reading many years ago that the juvenile stars of Children Of The Corn were forbidden to watch the film.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Corn_(1984_film)

Comment: The director and the cast usually ensure that the child actor is comfortable, to the point that young Danny Lloyd playing in "The Shining" was convinced that the movie is a family comedy.

Comment: You mean it wasn't?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6QgNuZcxTw

Comment: @Yasskier hehe this reminds me of Ender's Game. :)

Comment: @Pete wins for the best comment ROFL

Comment: Pretty much answer here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/604/to-what-extent-are-child-actors-exposed-to-the-violent-aspects-of-the-movie-they

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

The age of an actor with a role in the movie is irrelevant to whether they would be permitted to see it in a movie theater.

The content rating does not permit a juvenile watching the movie and so the actor would not be admitted to the screening in the first place.

Comment: We might want some jurisdiction clarification on this. Movie content restrictions in the US are not laws. In addition, only for NC-17 do theaters promise not to admit any minors even if they are accompanied. Minors accompanied by adults are admitted to R movies, and in practice most teenagers older than 13-15 or so can get into R movies by merely claiming to be 17. Also, at an actual movie premier with the red carpet and press there, it’s a whole different thing. Some child actors and/or their parents may not want the child to see it, but if parents agree, no one would stop them from attending

Comment: "The age of an actor with a role in the movie is irrelevant to whether they would be permitted to see it in a movie theater." I think you messed up the phrasing of that.